# Not able to read Interrupt Status Register on MAX30102

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, embedded, cortex-m3, lpc1768

I am currently trying to develop a pulse oximeter. For this I use the MAX30102 sensor and the NXP LPC1768 microcontroller. The communication is done via I2C.

I have configured the MAX30102 sensor to generate an interrupt as soon as the FIFO is full.

As soon as I start the program in debug mode, an interrupt is generated (debug jumps to the interrupt service routine and the logic analyzer shows that the interrupt line goes low).

**When I try to read the MAX30102's interrupt status registers on this first interrupt, I get a value of 0x00.** And no other interrupt is generated either. I suspect this is because the I2C read of the interrupt status register is not working properly, and thus the interrupt on the MAX30102 is not reset.

However, if I read the FIFO data register interrupts are continuously generated because reading this register resets the interrupts on the MAX30102.

But now to the whimsical part. **If I read other registers of the MAX30102 with the same I2C read function, I get values**. E.g. the FIFO_CONFIG register, in which I have written before. There I get by reading the same value that I have written into the register.

**But why does the reading of the interrupt status register with the same function not work?**

I traced the I2C_Read_Function for reading both registers with a logic analyzer and it was correct for both registers.

**Does anyone of you have any general ideas what this problem could be and what I can try,** because I'm getting desperate with this project?! I have already tried a lot, so I am grateful for any solution that I have not yet pursued.

Following my code. I tried to cut it to the important parts, but i can not narrow it down more.

main.c :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"LPC17xx.h"
#include"i2c.h"
#include"MAX30102.h"
#include"UART.h"
#include"ext1_int.h"
extern volatile bool interrupt;


int main()
{   
    uint8_tint_status1= 0;
    uint8_tint_status2= 0;
    
    I2C0Init();
    
    uart0_init();
    
    set_INT_Prio();
    
    ext1_int_init();   
    
    if(!max30102_reset())
        while(1);                   //Error
    if(!max30102_init(SpO2_Mode))
        while(1);                       //Error
    while(1)
    {       
        if(interrupt == true)
        {   
            NVIC_DisableIRQ(EINT1_IRQn);
                
            if(!max30102_read_reg(INT_STA1_REG, &int_status1))
                while(1);                   //Error
            if(!max30102_read_reg(INT_STA2_REG, &int_status2))
                while(1);                   //Error
            
            //if(int_status1 == xxx)//read FIFOinterrupt = false;
            
            NVIC_EnableIRQ(EINT1_IRQn);
        }
    }
}
```

ext1_int.h :

```
#ifndef__EXT1_INT_H
#define__EXT1_INT_H
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"LPC17xx.h"
void ext1_int_init(void);
void EINT1_IRQHandler(void);
void set_INT_Prio(void);
#endif//__EXT1_INT_H
```

ext1_int.c :

```
#include"ext1_int.h"
#include"MAX30102.h"
volatile bool interrupt;
void ext1_int_init(){
    LPC_SC->EXTMODE |= (1<<1);                              //Edge triggered 
    EINT0LPC_SC->EXTPOLAR &= ~(1<<1);                            //Falling Edge bzw. low active 
   LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 &= ~(3<<22);                    //Clear bits 22&23 to be updated
   LPC_PINCON->PINSEL4 |= (1<<22);                     //ENABLE EINT1 on GPIO2.11
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EINT1_IRQn);
}
void EINT1_IRQHandler(){
     LPC_SC->EXTINT     |= (1<<1);                  // clear Interrupt flag 
interrupt = true;
}
void set_INT_Prio(void){
     NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(0x04);
    NVIC_SetPriority(I2C0_IRQn,5);
    NVIC_SetPriority(EINT1_IRQn, 29);
}
```

MAX30102.h

```
#ifndef __MAX30102_HPP
#define __MAX30102_HPP
//Status
#define INT_STA1_REG 0x00
#define INT_STA2_REG 0x01
#define INT_ENA1_REG 0x02
#define INT_ENA2_REG 0x03
#define FIFO_WR_PTR 0x04
#define FIFO_OVF_COUNT 0x05
#define FIFO_RD_PTR 0x06
#define FIFO_DATA_REG 0x07

//Configuration Registers
#define FIFO_CONFIG_REG 0x08
#define MODE_CONFIG_REG 0x09
#define SPO2_CONFIG_REG 0x0A
#define LED_PULSE_AMPL_1    0x0C
#define LED_PULSE_AMPL_2    0x0D
#define MULTI_LED_CONTR_REG_1 0x11
#define MULTI_LED_CONTR_REG_2 0x12

//MAX30102 I2C Address
#define MAX30102_WR_ADDR 0xAE
#define MAX30102_RD_ADDR 0xAF
#define PORT_USED   0               
#define HR_Mode 0x02                //Red LED only
#define SpO2_Mode 0x03          //RED & IR LED
#define MulitLED_Mode 0x07  //RED & IR LED

#include <stdbool.h>   
#include <stdint.h>
#include "i2c.h"
bool max30102_reset(void);
bool max30102_init(uint8_t Mode);
bool max30102_read_reg(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *data);
bool max30102_write_reg(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t data);
#endif //__MAX30102_HPP
```

MAX30102.c

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "MAX30102.h"


extern volatile uint8_t I2CMasterBuffer[I2C_PORT_NUM][BUFSIZE];
extern volatile uint8_t I2CSlaveBuffer[I2C_PORT_NUM][BUFSIZE];
extern volatile uint32_t I2CReadLength[I2C_PORT_NUM];
extern volatile uint32_t I2CWriteLength[I2C_PORT_NUM];



bool max30102_reset(void)
{
    if(!max30102_write_reg(MODE_CONFIG_REG, 0x40))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
bool max30102_init(uint8_t Mode)
{
        if(!max30102_write_reg(INT_ENA1_REG, 0x80))     //A_FULL=1, PPG_RDY_EN=0 ALC_OVF_EN=0 -> 0x80
            while(1);
        if(!max30102_write_reg(INT_ENA2_REG, 0x00))     //DIE_TEMP_RDY_EN = 0
            while(1);
    
        if(!max30102_write_reg(FIFO_WR_PTR, 0x00))
            while(1);
        if(!max30102_write_reg(FIFO_OVF_COUNT, 0x00))
            while(1);
        if(!max30102_write_reg(FIFO_RD_PTR, 0x00))
            while(1);
        
        if(!max30102_write_reg(FIFO_CONFIG_REG, 0xE0))  //SMP_AVE=32(111), FIFO_ROLLOVER_EN=0, FIFO_A_FULL=32(0000) ->1110 0000=0xE0
            while(1);
        
        if(!max30102_write_reg(MODE_CONFIG_REG, Mode))
            while(1);
        
        if(!max30102_write_reg(SPO2_CONFIG_REG, 0x0F))          //SPO2ADC_RGE=7.81 pA LSB Size(00b), SPO2_SR=400 (011b), LED_PW=411us(18bits ADC Resolution) (11b) -> x000 1111 = 0x0F
            while(1);
        
        if(!max30102_write_reg(LED_PULSE_AMPL_1, 0x32))         //IR-LED current = 10mA
            while(1);
        
        
        if(!max30102_write_reg(LED_PULSE_AMPL_2, 0x32))         //RED-LED current = 10mA
            while(1);

    
    return true;
}

bool max30102_read_reg(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *data)
{
    uint8_t i = 0;
    //clear Buffer
    for (i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++ )
    {
        I2CMasterBuffer[PORT_USED][i] = 0;
    }

    /* Write SLA(W), address, SLA(R), and read one byte back. */
    I2CWriteLength[PORT_USED] = 2;
    I2CReadLength[PORT_USED] = 1;                                           
    I2CMasterBuffer[PORT_USED][0] = MAX30102_WR_ADDR;
    I2CMasterBuffer[PORT_USED][1] = reg_addr;       /* address */
    I2CMasterBuffer[PORT_USED][2] = MAX30102_RD_ADDR;

    if(I2CEngine(PORT_USED) != I2C_OK)
        return false;

    *data = (uint8_t) I2CSlaveBuffer[PORT_USED][0];

    return true;
}

bool max30102_write_reg(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t data)
{
    uint8_t i = 0;
    //clear Buffer
    for (i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++ )
    {
        I2CMasterBuffer[PORT_USED][i] = 0;
    }

    I2CWriteLength[PORT_USED] = 3;
    I2CReadLength[PORT_USED] = 0;
    I2CMasterBuffer[PORT_USED][0] = MAX30102_WR_ADDR;
    I2CMasterBuffer[PORT_USED][1] = reg_addr;       /* address */
    I2CMasterBuffer[PORT_USED][2] = data;               /* Data0 */


    if(I2CEngine(PORT_USED) != I2C_OK)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

i2c.h :

```
/****************************************************************************
 *   $Id:: i2c.h 5865 2010-12-08 21:42:21Z usb00423                         $
 *   Project: NXP LPC17xx I2C example
 *
 *   Description:
 *     This file contains I2C code header definition.
 *
 ****************************************************************************
 * Software that is described herein is for illustrative purposes only
 * which provides customers with programming information regarding the
 * products. This software is supplied "AS IS" without any warranties.
 * NXP Semiconductors assumes no responsibility or liability for the
 * use of the software, conveys no license or title under any patent,
 * copyright, or mask work right to the product. NXP Semiconductors
 * reserves the right to make changes in the software without
 * notification. NXP Semiconductors also make no representation or
 * warranty that such application will be suitable for the specified
 * use without further testing or modification.
****************************************************************************/

#ifndef __I2C_H
#define __I2C_H


/* If I2C SEEPROM is tested, make sure FAST_MODE_PLUS is 0.
For board to board test, this flag can be turned on. */

#include <stdint.h>
#include "LPC17xx.h"

#define FAST_MODE_PLUS      0

#define I2C_PORT_NUM        3
#define BUFSIZE             64 
#define MAX_TIMEOUT         0x00FFFFFF

static LPC_I2C_TypeDef (* const LPC_I2C[I2C_PORT_NUM]) = { LPC_I2C0, LPC_I2C1, LPC_I2C2 };

#define I2CMASTER           0x01
#define I2CSLAVE            0x02

#define PCF8594_ADDR        0xA0
#define READ_WRITE          0x01

#define MAX30102_WR_ADDR 0xAE
#define MAX30102_RD_ADDR 0xAF

#define RD_BIT              0x01

#define I2C_IDLE              0
#define I2C_STARTED           1
#define I2C_RESTARTED         2
#define I2C_REPEATED_START    3
#define DATA_ACK              4
#define DATA_NACK             5
#define I2C_BUSY              6
#define I2C_NO_DATA           7
#define I2C_NACK_ON_ADDRESS   8
#define I2C_NACK_ON_DATA      9
#define I2C_ARBITRATION_LOST  10
#define I2C_TIME_OUT          11
#define I2C_OK                12

#define I2CONSET_I2EN       (0x1<<6)  /* I2C Control Set Register */
#define I2CONSET_AA         (0x1<<2)
#define I2CONSET_SI         (0x1<<3)
#define I2CONSET_STO        (0x1<<4)
#define I2CONSET_STA        (0x1<<5)

#define I2CONCLR_AAC        (0x1<<2)  /* I2C Control clear Register */
#define I2CONCLR_SIC        (0x1<<3)
#define I2CONCLR_STAC       (0x1<<5)
#define I2CONCLR_I2ENC      (0x1<<6)

#define I2DAT_I2C           0x00000000  /* I2C Data Reg */
#define I2ADR_I2C           0x00000000  /* I2C Slave Address Reg */
#define I2SCLH_SCLH         0x00000080  /* I2C SCL Duty Cycle High Reg */
#define I2SCLL_SCLL         0x00000080  /* I2C SCL Duty Cycle Low Reg */
#define I2SCLH_HS_SCLH      0x00000008  /* Fast Plus I2C SCL Duty Cycle High Reg */
#define I2SCLL_HS_SCLL      0x00000008  /* Fast Plus I2C SCL Duty Cycle Low Reg */



extern void I2C0_IRQHandler( void );
extern void I2C0Init( void );
extern uint32_t I2CStart( uint32_t portNum );
extern uint32_t I2CStop( uint32_t portNum );
extern uint32_t I2CEngine( uint32_t portNum );


#endif /* end __I2C_H */
```

i2c.c

```
/****************************************************************************
 *   $Id:: i2c.c 5865 2010-12-08 21:42:21Z usb00423                         $
 *   Project: NXP LPC17xx I2C example
 *
 *   Description:
 *     This file contains I2C code example which include I2C initialization,
 *     I2C interrupt handler, and APIs for I2C access.
 *
 ****************************************************************************
 * Software that is described herein is for illustrative purposes only
 * which provides customers with programming information regarding the
 * products. This software is supplied "AS IS" without any warranties.
 * NXP Semiconductors assumes no responsibility or liability for the
 * use of the software, conveys no license or title under any patent,
 * copyright, or mask work right to the product. NXP Semiconductors
 * reserves the right to make changes in the software without
 * notification. NXP Semiconductors also make no representation or
 * warranty that such application will be suitable for the specified
 * use without further testing or modification.
****************************************************************************/
#include "type.h"
#include "lpc17xx.h"
#include "i2c.h"

volatile uint32_t I2CMasterState[I2C_PORT_NUM] = {I2C_IDLE,I2C_IDLE,I2C_IDLE};
volatile uint32_t timeout[I2C_PORT_NUM] = {0, 0, 0};

volatile uint8_t I2CMasterBuffer[I2C_PORT_NUM][BUFSIZE];
volatile uint8_t I2CSlaveBuffer[I2C_PORT_NUM][BUFSIZE];
volatile uint32_t I2CCount[I2C_PORT_NUM] = {0, 0, 0};
volatile uint32_t I2CReadLength[I2C_PORT_NUM];
volatile uint32_t I2CWriteLength[I2C_PORT_NUM];

volatile uint32_t RdIndex0 = 0, RdIndex1 = 0, RdIndex2 = 0;
volatile uint32_t WrIndex0 = 0, WrIndex1 = 0, WrIndex2 = 0;

void I2C0_IRQHandler(void)
{   
  uint8_t StatValue;

  timeout[0] = 0;
  /* this handler deals with master read and master write only */
  StatValue = LPC_I2C0->I2STAT;
  switch ( StatValue )
  {
    case 0x08:          /* A Start condition is issued. */
    WrIndex0 = 0;
    LPC_I2C0->I2DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[0][WrIndex0++];
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = (I2CONCLR_SIC | I2CONCLR_STAC);
    break;
    
    case 0x10:          /* A repeated started is issued */
    RdIndex0 = 0;
    /* Send SLA with R bit set, */
    LPC_I2C0->I2DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[0][WrIndex0++];
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = (I2CONCLR_SIC | I2CONCLR_STAC);
    break;
    
    case 0x18:          /* Regardless, it's a ACK */
    if ( I2CWriteLength[0] == 1 )
    {
      LPC_I2C0->I2CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
      I2CMasterState[0] = I2C_NO_DATA;
    }
    else
    {
      LPC_I2C0->I2DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[0][WrIndex0++];
    }
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
    break;

    case 0x28:  /* Data byte has been transmitted, regardless ACK or NACK */
    if ( WrIndex0 < I2CWriteLength[0] )
    {   
      LPC_I2C0->I2DAT = I2CMasterBuffer[0][WrIndex0++]; /* this should be the last one */
    }
    else
    {
      if ( I2CReadLength[0] != 0 )
      {
        LPC_I2C0->I2CONSET = I2CONSET_STA;  /* Set Repeated-start flag */
      }
      else
      {
        LPC_I2C0->I2CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
        I2CMasterState[0] = I2C_OK;
      }
    }
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
    break;

    case 0x30:
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
    I2CMasterState[0] = I2C_NACK_ON_DATA;
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
    break;
    
    case 0x40:  /* Master Receive, SLA_R has been sent */
    if ( (RdIndex0 + 1) < I2CReadLength[0] )
    {
      /* Will go to State 0x50 */
      LPC_I2C0->I2CONSET = I2CONSET_AA; /* assert ACK after data is received */
    }
    else
    {
      /* Will go to State 0x58 */
      LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_AAC;    /* assert NACK after data is received */
    }
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
    break;
    
    case 0x50:  /* Data byte has been received, regardless following ACK or NACK */
    I2CSlaveBuffer[0][RdIndex0++] = LPC_I2C0->I2DAT;
    if ( (RdIndex0 + 1) < I2CReadLength[0] )
    {   
      LPC_I2C0->I2CONSET = I2CONSET_AA; /* assert ACK after data is received */
    }
    else
    {
      LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_AAC;    /* assert NACK on last byte */
    }
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
    break;
    
    case 0x58:
    I2CSlaveBuffer[0][RdIndex0++] = LPC_I2C0->I2DAT;
    I2CMasterState[0] = I2C_OK;
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;  /* Set Stop flag */
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;  /* Clear SI flag */
    break;

    case 0x20:      /* regardless, it's a NACK */
    case 0x48:
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
    I2CMasterState[0] = I2C_NACK_ON_ADDRESS;
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;
    break;
    
    case 0x38:      /* Arbitration lost, in this example, we don't
                    deal with multiple master situation */
    default:
    I2CMasterState[0] = I2C_ARBITRATION_LOST;
    LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC; 
    break;
  }
  return;
}

uint32_t I2CStart( uint32_t portNum )
{
  uint32_t retVal = FALSE;
 
  timeout[portNum] = 0;
  /*--- Issue a start condition ---*/
  LPC_I2C[portNum]->I2CONSET = I2CONSET_STA;    /* Set Start flag */
    
  /*--- Wait until START transmitted ---*/
  while( 1 )
  {
    if ( I2CMasterState[portNum] == I2C_STARTED )
    {
      retVal = TRUE;
      break;   
    }
    if ( timeout[portNum] >= MAX_TIMEOUT )
    {
      retVal = FALSE;
      break;
    }
    timeout[portNum]++;
  }
  return( retVal );
}

uint32_t I2CStop( uint32_t portNum )
{
  LPC_I2C[portNum]->I2CONSET = I2CONSET_STO;      /* Set Stop flag */
  LPC_I2C[portNum]->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_SIC;  /* Clear SI flag */
            
  /*--- Wait for STOP detected ---*/
  while( LPC_I2C[portNum]->I2CONSET & I2CONSET_STO );
  return TRUE;
}

void I2C0Init( void )
{
  LPC_SC->PCONP |= (1 << 7);

  /* set PIO0.27 and PIO0.28 to I2C0 SDA and SCL */
  /* function to 01 on both SDA and SCL. */
  LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 &= ~((0x03<<22)|(0x03<<24));
  LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 |= ((0x01<<22)|(0x01<<24));   
 
  /*--- Clear flags ---*/
  LPC_I2C0->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_AAC | I2CONCLR_SIC | I2CONCLR_STAC | I2CONCLR_I2ENC;   

  /*--- Reset registers ---*/
#if FAST_MODE_PLUS
  LPC_PINCON->I2CPADCFG |= ((0x1<<0)|(0x1<<2));
  LPC_I2C0->I2SCLL   = I2SCLL_HS_SCLL;
  LPC_I2C0->I2SCLH   = I2SCLH_HS_SCLH;
#else
  LPC_PINCON->I2CPADCFG &= ~((0x1<<0)|(0x1<<2));
  /*LPC_I2C0->I2SCLL   = I2SCLL_SCLL;
  LPC_I2C0->I2SCLH   = I2SCLH_SCLH;*/
    LPC_I2C0->I2SCLL   = 0x20;      //für ~400 kHz
  LPC_I2C0->I2SCLH   = 0x1F;        //für ~400 kHz
#endif

  /* Install interrupt handler */
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(I2C0_IRQn);

  LPC_I2C0->I2CONSET = I2CONSET_I2EN;
  return;
}

uint32_t I2CEngine( uint32_t portNum )
{
  /*--- Issue a start condition ---*/
  LPC_I2C[portNum]->I2CONSET = I2CONSET_STA;    /* Set Start flag */

  I2CMasterState[portNum] = I2C_BUSY;   

  while ( I2CMasterState[portNum] == I2C_BUSY )
  {
    if ( timeout[portNum] >= MAX_TIMEOUT )
    {
      I2CMasterState[portNum] = I2C_TIME_OUT;
      break;
    }
    timeout[portNum]++;
  }
  LPC_I2C[portNum]->I2CONCLR = I2CONCLR_STAC;

  return ( I2CMasterState[portNum] );
}
```

Comment: The purpose of posting the code is to either rule out a software issue or find it. A general answer without looking at your code would really just be a bunch of guesses that won't get you an answer.

Comment: @dabo Please ask a specific question

Comment: @Justme added the code, so you can have a look :)

Comment: @VoltageSpike Why does Interrupt Status Register always give 0x00, if reading other registers works perfectly?

Comment: Why do you enable external interrupts even before initializing the chip that is supposed to generate interrupts? Also, why are you even using interrupts, if the only thing you do in the interrupt is set a flag variable (which you have commented out) and then poll for the flag variable in the main loop? I mean, it would be much simpler to just read the GPIO pin in main loop and act based on that. Just because a chip has a pin named "interrupt", it does not mean you have to have it generating interrupt requests on a MCU. Also that code hangs in while(1) after resetting the chip so it never runs.

Comment: @Justme Sorry there were a few copy paste mistakes about commented code, but I correctet them. Thanks for the other tips!